# loop through array using foreach laravel blade template

Tags: foreach, view, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I want to count the number of comments posted on each video. i have been constantly failed to get the desired result.

Here is the data comming from my `DB`

```
["data",{"res":[{"videoId":"10"},{"videoId":"40"}],"comments":[{"videoId":"10","total":1},{"videoId":"40","total":2}]}]
```

result should be in the desired format given below:

```
videoId ----- total comments
10             1
40             2
```

Here is the screen shot attached

[image]

Comment: can you add your controller and blade code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one video has so many comments that is being posted by user
Here is my laravel Relationship that is `one to many`

```
public function GetVideoComments(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'videoId', 'videoId');

    }
```

Here is the count the number of comments posted on each video.

```
$posts = VideoComment::withCount('GetVideoComments')->get();
$posts->sum('comments_count');
```

the above give be the number of total comments posted on each video.